# White Spots Appearing in Image Containing Outline

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, rgb

I want my image to look like this.

[No Spots Appearing in Purple Region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3gfa.jpg)

However, my image looks like this, with white spots sometimes showing up in the area that is supposed to be "outlined."

[Spots Appearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gGHQ.png)

Basically, I coded an eroded version of an image [Eroded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90Ajb.png) as well as a dilated version [Dilated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMA2L.png). If you would like to see the code for those two versions, please let me know and I will add it.

My goal is to make the white regions in the eroded image purple and place these purple eroded letters/numbers inside of the dilated letters/numbers. The **onechannel** function only displays a specified R/G/B channel of a given image.

```
def outline():

red,green,blue = range(3)
imgD = dilation(chars,7,20,480)
imgE = erosion(chars,7,20,480)
imgDOr = imgD.copy()
imgDcop = onechannel(imgD,0)
imgDcop[:,:,0] = 128
imgEcop = onechannel(imgE,2)
imgEcop[:,:,2] = 128

for i in range (0,len(imgD)):
    for j in range (0,len(imgD[0])):
        if imgE[i,j,0] == 255:
            imgDOr[i,j,0] = imgDcop[i,j,0]
            imgDOr[i,j,1] = imgDcop[i,j,1]
            imgDOr[i,j,2] = imgEcop[i,j,2]

imageshow(imgDOr)

print(outline())
```

Comment: I've never used this function. However, the result image appears to be pixelated . Are both images the same resolution?

Comment: Yes, both images are the same resolution.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in your `erosion` function where it does not set the white pixels to `255,255,255`. If you inspect the RGB of the eroded image you posted you will see that the first channel of the white areas has values ranging from 250 to 255, and the grayish edges are starting from `239,239,239`. You need to either fix the `erosion` function to strictly set all white areas to absolute `255,255,255` or relax the condition in your `outline` function from `if imgE[i,j,0] == 255:` to something like `if 255 - imgE[i,j,0] <= 16:`.